# Twitter's Bootstrap Active Buttons are not being applying any style

Tags: css, internet-explorer, virtual-machine, twitter-bootstrap

I have this rails application using twitter's bootstrap 2.0 for styling, the problem is when I press a button on internet explorer, it becomes active and realizes the correct action... but the buttons remains with the same style so that's a problem

I'm developing on my mac, and trying out with a windows xp virtual machine with virtual box, the debug bar and the built in ie8 developer tools are so bad, and slow...but that's maybe because of the virtual machine and because i'm serving the app from my host computer and entering in the guest OS like http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:3000 (XXX... is for my IP)

what do you recommend me for this?

EDIT:

here's my definition for the html (html5 doctype) with haml

```
#categorias.row
    .btn-group{ 'data-toggle' => 'buttons-checkbox' }
      - categorias.each do |categoria|
        .categoria{ :id => "categoria_#{categoria.id}" }
          %button.btn{ :id => "categoria_#{categoria.id}_btn" }= categoria.nombre
          - categoria.subcategorias.each do |subcategoria|
            = hidden_field_tag "sub_categorias[#{subcategoria.id}]", "categoria-" + subcategoria.nombre.slugify, 'data-genero' => subcategoria.genero
```

that's what it looks like in chrome

[image: the chrome output of the button]

and the source

[image: chrome html and active css class]

the ie 8 output

[image: the button with the active class and output]

and the ie 8 computed css

[image: computed ie8 css]

Comment: I recommend sharing some code. What does the view code look like? What does the output html look like?

Comment: Have you submitted a [bug report](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues) yet?

Comment: In IE8 i changed all display:inline-block for display:inline and the style worked

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove data-spy from my body tag.

I *think* the reason is scrollspy requires the id's to exist in the dom. But I haven't tested it.